Is で particle also used as purpose marker? And in 生で, is it marking the method of eating
Please help me understand the use of de particle in below examples.

中国語やスペイン語など、仕事で役に立ちそうな外国語を勉強したいです (I want to study foreign languages that would be useful for work, like Chinese or Spanish.)
野菜を生で食べます。(I eat vegetables raw.)

In the 1st example, if de particle marks shigoto as purpose, like being useful for purpose of work, can't we use に, as we know ni is a purpose marker.
And in the 2nd example, is the particle de marking the method of eating? Pls help me.
Am I missing something?

In the first sentence, you can use both に (as a purpose marker) and で (as a location/situation marker). 仕事に役に立つ sounds like "useful for work", and 仕事で役に立つ sounds more like "useful at work", but they are equally fine here.
In the second sentence, で is a condition/scope marker rather than a method/means marker. Think of 生で as "in a raw state" rather than "using raw". In English, "raw" is an adjective, but 生 is a noun in Japanese, so you need to attach で to make it modify a verb.

Thankyou so much, it is really helpful
